# Adding Identity API Endpoints and Authentication to a website using a REST API

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, code-generation, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I'm mystified by how the SignInManager works with the IdentityAPIEndpoints.
We have a two-tiered system with a front end and an API.
We have added the API endpoints to the backend, and those are working.

We have this code

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services
    .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<UserLoginModel>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LoginContext>()
    .AddSignInManager(); // <<<---

app.MapGroup("/account").MapIdentityApi<UserLoginModel>();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

But how do I get the SignInManager to know about the login page and how does it know where to redirect to after login?
Especially considering that they are in the front end project.
My plan is to re-write the pages from the UI scaffolding to call the API, but I can't see how to get the login page called in the first place. I'm assuming that the SignInManager is supposed to help with that.

Comment: how does it know where to redirect to after login?--In my opinion,it should be configured in your front end

Comment: What't your front end? The login endpoingt would return 200 statue code with accesstoken/refresh token after you've logined successfully.and then token should only be used to access the protected the resources in your api project(for example,user profile)

Comment: @RuikaiFeng  "My plan is to re-write the pages from the UI scaffolding" so those would be Razor pages.

Comment: "after you've logined successfully" That's the sticking point isn't it? How does it get to the login page? In normal operation, I believe that the SignInManager redirects it to the Login page.

Comment: "how does it know where to redirect to after login?" IDK. I'm assuming that it doesn't. It gets to the API controller with an Authorize attribute, and middleware steps in, checks the cookie, and sends it to the login page if needed. Then it continues on from where it left off with the controller.

Comment: it has no relationship with SigninManager,you could configure the path with builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie() method